# Why stdout will be flushed when it reaches newline?

Tags: python, file, io

When I attempt to directly write into `stdout` it does not flush until I manually flush or close the file.

```py
Python 3.8.10 (default, May  4 2021, 00:00:00) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20201125 (Red Hat 10.2.1-9)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> f = open(1, 'w')
>>> f.write('hello world!')
12
>>> 
>>> f.close()
hello world!>>>
```

But if my string ends with a new line it immediately flushes the file.

```py
>>> f = open(1, 'w')
>>> 
>>> f.write('hello\n')
hello
6
>>>
```

Even if the `\n` character is placed in the middle of the string the whole content is flushed.

```py
>>> f.write('hello\nworld\t')
hello
world   12
```

My question is that who is responsible for this behavior? OS, file system or the Python itself?